# Why does this C++ code output the result?

Tags: c++

This is the `C++` code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;


int a=8;

int fun(int &a)
{
    a=a*a;
    return a;
}

int main()
{

    cout << a << endl \
        << fun(a) << endl \
        << a << endl;
        return 0;
}
```

why does it output:

### `64 64 8`

the `<<` operator's associativity is left to right, so why not output `8 64 64`?

Does it have the relation to the sequence point and the effect side?

Comment: Your question isn't clear. The final sentence needs to be rephrased, and you need to share what you expected the outcome to be. As it currently stands, the output makes sense.

Comment: it's pretty clear that he expected output to be 8 64 64, at least I thought it was clear

Comment: It is clear.... I don't know what Mahmoud is talking about. There is nothing wrong with this question...

Comment: @MahmoudAl-Qudsi: I have added the output I expect

Comment: http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/056.htm

Comment: Side note: You don't need those backslashes.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Associativity and evaluation order are not the same thing. The expression `a << b << c` is equivalent to `(a << b) << c` due to left-to-right associativity, but when it comes to evaluation order, the compiler is free to evaluate `c` first then `a << b` and, likewise, it can evaluate `b` before it evaluates `a`. In fact, it can even evaluate the terms in the order `b` → `c` → `a` if it wants, and it just might if it concludes that such an order will maximise performance by minimising pipeline stalls, cache misses, etc.